# Hello, I cannot get public String getGenderName() to output what the User would Input

Tags: java

I cannot get public String getGenderName() to output what the User would Input. It just keep outputting **Wrong Input**. Please Help me I am kinda of new to java so please no half explanation please. What's you wrong with my code? Please let me know, also if someone would know how to implement **public enum Gender** i would also be interested in see your views on that also

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private static String gender;
private int dependents;
private double annualSalary;
private NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
private static Scanner scan;
private static char sex;

public Employee() {     
    firstName = "not given";
    lastName = "not given";
    gender = "";
    dependents = 0;
    annualSalary = 20.000;      
}

public Employee(String first, String last, char sex, int dep, double salary) {
    setFirstName(first);
    setLastName(last);
    Character.toString(sex);;
    setDependents(dep);
    setAnnualSalary(salary);
}

public double calculatePay() {
    return annualSalary / 52;
}

public void displayEmployee() {
    System.out.println("First Name: " + getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + getLastName());
    System.out.println("Gender: " + getGenderName());
    System.out.println("Dependents: " + getDependents());
    System.out.println("Annual Salary: " + nf.format(getAnnualSalary()));        
    System.out.println("Weekly Pay: " + nf.format(calculatePay()));
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

***public String getGenderName()
{
       if ("m".equalsIgnoreCase(gender))
           return "Male";
        if ("f".equalsIgnoreCase(gender))
           return "Female";
       else 
           return "Wrong Input";
}***

public void setDependents(int dependents) {
    this.dependents = dependents;
}

public int getDependents() {
    return dependents;
}

public void setAnnualSalary(double annualSalary) {
    this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
}

public double getAnnualSalary() {
    return annualSalary;
}

public static void displayDivider(String outputTitle) {
    System.out.println("**************** " + outputTitle + " ****************");        
}

public static String getInput(String inputType) {
     System.out.println("Enter the " + inputType + ": ");
     scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     String input = scan.next();
     return input;
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create an Employee object using the default constructor
    displayDivider("Create an Employee object using the default constructor");
    Employee employee1 = new Employee();
    Employee.setGender(Employee.gender);
    String input;
    int dependents;
    double annualSalary;
    input = getInput("First Name");
    employee1.setFirstName(input);
    input = getInput("Last Name");
    employee1.setLastName(input);
    input = getInput("Gender");
    setSex(input.charAt(0));
    Employee.setGender("gender");
    input = getInput("Dependents");
    dependents = Integer.parseInt(input);
    employee1.setDependents(dependents);
    input = getInput("Annual Salary");
    annualSalary = Double.parseDouble(input);
    employee1.setAnnualSalary(annualSalary);
    displayDivider("Employee Information");
    employee1.displayEmployee();
    displayDivider("Create a second Employee object using the multi-argument constructor");
    Employee employee2 = new Employee("John", "Doe", 'M', 3, 46000.0);
    displayDivider("Employee Information");
    employee2.displayEmployee();
}

private static void setGender(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * @return the sex
 */
public static char getSex() {
    return sex;
}

/**
 * @param sex the sex to set
 */
public static void setSex(char sex) {
    Employee.sex = sex;
}
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the Annual Salary: 

Enter the First Name: 
g
Enter the Last Name: 
hhj
Enter the Gender: 
m
Enter the Dependents: 
7
Enter the Annual Salary: 
9
**************** Employee Information ****************
First Name: g
Last Name: hhj
Gender: **Wrong Input**
Dependents: 7
Annual Salary: $9.00
Weekly Pay: $0.17
**************** Sample Employee Information ****************
First Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Gender: **Wrong Input**
Dependents: 3
Annual Salary: $46,000.00
Weekly Pay: $884.62
```

Comment: setGender is not implemented, so you never change the value of gender. Also setGender() is a private static method?

Comment: Have I not implemented it correctly in the public Static void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are not assigning anything to `gender` in constructor. You should write:

```
gender = Character.toString(sex);
```

and your `setGender` method is empty

```
private static void setGender(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Its should be:

```
public static void setGender(String string) {
    gender = string;

}
```

**Note:** You should not keep gender as `static`, does not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks that work for the sample method it is now showing Male. But for the User input I still get wrong input

Comment: Why do you have `sex` and `gender` as two separate fields ? you should call only `setGender` method wherever you are calling `setSex` method.

Comment: When i input the gender of the employee (M,F,m,f,Male,Female) i still get wrong input for reason. but it is working in my sample section so I am half way there thank u for all you help

Comment: Because you are passing character in a string

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
Employee.setGender("Gender");
```

So the gender variable gets the string 'Gender' which is never m or f.
Why are gender and sex static ? Are all your employees of the same sex !
Make them non-static and in your main method:

```
input = getInput("Gender");
employee1.setGender(input.charAt(0));
```

I don't understand why you need an extra variable sex.

To have a Gender as an enulm:

```
public class Employee {

    public enum Gender {
        Male('m'), Female('f');
        private char sign;
        private Gender(char sign )
       {
            this.sign=sign;
        }
        public static Gender valueOf(final char s)
        {
            switch(s){
                case 'm': return Male;
                 case 'f':return Female;
            }
            System.err.println("invalid gender:"+s);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Gender gender;

    public void setGender(Gender g) 
    {
        this.gender=g;
    }
    public Gender getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

Example how it can be used:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    input = getInput("Gender");
    employee1.setGender(Gender.valueOf(input.charAt(0)));
}
```

Comment: Okay thank I took out the extra sex variable ur right. Okay for the  pointed me in the right direction to answer the second part of my question THANK U  I need to type employee1.setGender(input.substring(0)); instead of employee1.setGender(input.charAt(0));. This my first time on this this is amazing everyone was very helpful thank u

Comment: Did that after I correct everything that all that yall showed me what was wrong and the enum worked like a charm thanks

Comment: be carefull: input.substring(0) will not return the first character but will return the string starting at position 0 = complete string. If you want to do it with substring you have to use input.substring(0,1);